# How to increment row of a gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I am fetching data into a gridview from a table.My gridview have 3 text box and one dropdown control.I want to fetch data one by one row from database.After fetching each row i want to increment the row of a grid view and again fetch it.

Here is my code

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand("proc_bcdet", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand2.Parameters.Add("@btcode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["btcode"];
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
adp.SelectCommand = sqlCommand2;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

int rowIndex = 0;
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gvCashReceipt.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("txtlgroup");
        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)gvCashReceipt.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("txtamt");
        TextBox box3 = (TextBox)gvCashReceipt.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("txtnarr");
        Label lb1 = (Label)gvCashReceipt.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("lbllcode");
        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)gvCashReceipt.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("drprledger");


        //Fill the DropDownList with Data 
        ddl1.DataSource = module.Query("Select Name from AccMast where  LGcode in (2,3,4) order by Lcode");
        ddl1.DataBind();


        if (i < dt.Rows.Count)
        {

            //Assign the value from DataTable to the TextBox 
            box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Lgname"].ToString();
            box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Amt"].ToString();
            box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Narr"].ToString();
            lb1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Lcode"].ToString();
            //Set the Previous Selected Items on Each DropDownList  on Postbacks 
            ddl1.ClearSelection();
            ddl1.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }

        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

after fetching first row i got an error 'index out of range' please help me...

Comment: "I want to fetch data one by one row from database" That is usually not a good idea. Fetch all the data you need on one call. Otherwise, you can be calling hundreds of queries per page load... and if hundreds of people hit that same page, the result is less than optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want the for loop when you can directly bind the data to the gridview.
However, if your requirement is to get an increment column, the best way to do it is to create a new Data table with a increment column and then merge it with your result Data table.

This link shows how to do this.
http://tinyurl.com/kv5v2zy

On a side note,try using Data Grid which is very versatile.

Hope this helps.